# How to add values from multiple DataGridViewCell and output them to TextBox?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm stuck here.
 I have a DataGridView with 8 columns (the 7th waits for user input and the 8th does some math). 
This is the Parent Form

[Parent Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpAsj.jpg)

When I click "Adauga" which means "Add", the Total Kcal textbox should update its value to
 kcal(column) * (cantitate=quantity) and Pret Total = Total Price update its value to pret=Price(column) * (cantitate)
 and it does so, but only for one row. Let me explain: As you can see above I clicked the 3rd (from up to bottom) button and it returned 618,10 (price is 10*1 quantity) (kcal is 618*1 qty) but if I also click the first button , look [They don't add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgXFN.jpg)

the values don't add to the previous ones, and I do not know how to do this.
This is the code :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            var pret = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value;
            var kcal = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;
            var qt = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value;
            int qty = int.Parse(qt.ToString());
            int kca = int.Parse(kcal.ToString()); 
            int pre = int.Parse(pret.ToString()); 
            int kcalTotal = 0, pretTotal = 0;
            kcalTotal = kcalTotal + (qty * kca); 
            pretTotal = pretTotal + (qty * pre);
            totalPR.Text = pretTotal.ToString();
            totalKC.Text = kcalTotal.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to sum up the values of the clicked rows. So after your first click, the price TextBox should Show 10, after the next one 23. If that's how you meant your question, you just have to add a few lines:

change

```
int kcalTotal = 0, pretTotal = 0;
```

to

```
int kcalTotal = 0, pretTotal = 0;
int.TryParse(totalKC.Text, out kcalTotal);
int.TryParse(totalPR.Text, out pretTotal);
```

Comment: If I do this, I get the error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: That's (probably) because the default value of your textboxes is empty. You either have to use `try-catch`, set the default value of the textboxes to `"0"` or use `int.TryParse`.
I edited my answer and changed it to the int.TryParse approach.

Comment: It works, thanks. Can you tell me the "magic" behind these lines of code? I'm new to C# WinForms, learning everyday :)
Btw, you used the TryParse approach, but which of the three you mentioned is the most effective?

Comment: Basically, if you just have the code as you had it before, you always add the new values to 0. If you want to keep your old values, you have to read the value that is already within the textboxes and add that value to the new one. With `int.Parse(string)` you can turn a string into a int.
However, if you pass a string that cannot be turned into an int (like `"abc"`, `10a2` or even an empty string) it throws an exception.
By using `int.TryParse`, it won't throw an expection and leave your value as it is if there is an error.

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks a lot for help!